# Mule ESB 3 - Use Axis 1.4 to consume a Web Service

Tags: web-services, mule, axis

I have a WSDL file that have a 'rpc' style and for this reason I can not use CXF to consume a Web Service. 
Therefore I used Axis (wsdl2java axis tool) to generate the stub classes but now i don't know how to call the service in Mule because I usually use  tag.

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Java component that uses the Axis client to make the web service call and invoke this Java component from your XML config.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I wea able to use CXF. Anyway, yor solution is correct